# print date in loop per hour with bash script

Tags: bash, date, ubuntu

I would like to write a bash script that prints out the date in the following format:

```
20120205_16
(year)(month)(day)_(24 hour)
```

so the command to do this for the current date is:

```
date +'20%y%m%d_%H'
```

What i would like to do is print every date like this (using a for loop or something) from a specified date to another. For example:

```
20120205_16 -> 20120305_18 would be:

20120205_16
20120205_17
20120205_18
...
20120305_17
20120305_18
```

Obviously the two hard bits here are specifying the date and incrementing by hour.

Is it possible to do this easily with date or another method?

Comment: Ah, I've just noticed you are using `20%y`. I believe you just want to use `%Y` which gives you the whole year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you get `time_t` values using the `%s` format:

```
start=$(date --date '5 feb 2012 16:00' +%s)
stop=$(date --date '5 mar 2012 18:00' +%s)
```

These are expressed in seconds. You can use a for loop on their values, increasing them by 1 hour (3600 seconds):

```
for t in $(seq ${start} 3600 ${stop})
do
    date --date @${t} +'%Y%m%d_%H'
done
```

Note the `@` which is used to express times obtained through `%+s` in the `--date` argument.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a set of command-line tools for date fiddling in general ([dateutils](http://hroptatyr.github.com/dateutils/)).  It's definitely not widely spread, but portable.

For this kind of task, `dseq` is your friend, your example boils down to:

```
dseq '2012-02-05 16:00:00' 1h '2012-03-05 18:00:00' -f '%Y%m%d_%H'
=>
20120205_16
20120205_17
20120205_18
  ...
20120305_16
20120305_17
20120305_18
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done nicely in Gawk:

```
gawk -v start="2011 10 10  10 00 00" \
     -v end="2011 11 10  10 00 00" '

BEGIN {
  time = mktime( start )
  end = mktime( end )
  while ( time <= end ) {
    print strftime( "%Y%m%d_%H", time )
    time +=3600
  }
}'
```